# Program will not run on CRONTAB

Tags: linux, debian, cron, deluge

I'm trying to have crontab run deluge-gtk run at a specified time but for some reason nothing happens. I'm on Debian 9.4 (stretch).

Here is what I have on my crontab file:

`30 16 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/deluge --ui=gtk`

I've also tried

`30 16 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/deluge-gtk`

None of them work. Can I get some enlightenment, please.

***ADDITIONAL INFO:***

With other jobs, **cron** is working fine. It's just not working for this **deluge** line I have

Comment: Before adding the commands to cron, try to run the command as normal command.  Also check for which user your are running the cron.

Comment: I can run the command fine both with my user. As far as I know, crontab jobs created under my user will run as my user, correct?

Comment: Think about this for a minute. If you are not logged in, should the application be opened on the currently logged in user's desktop?  Remember that Unix is a multi user system.

Answer (score 0):

See Kusalananda's comment about multi-user environment. Try

```
30 16 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/deluge --ui=gtk
```

Use `crontab -e` to edit your personal crontab.

Comment: I've already tried that on my personal crontab and still nothing